# pip-selfcheck.json with virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am using virtualenv in my python project and I noticed a file called
`pip-selfcheck.json`

What is the purpose of this file? Can I delete it from my project?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When it's there, `pip` will check that you have the latest version of `pip`. You can remove it.